# UIButton background image horizontal scale to fill while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I am trying to set the backgroundImage of a UIButton to an image that could be any size. The way I want to display tall images is for the images to expand to fill the button horizontally, and only show the top part of the image. So for a button with dimensions 100x200 and an image of 80x400, I want to scale the image to 100x500 and only show the top 200 pixels of that scaled image.

I am wondering if there is some way to alter how the background image fills the uibutton (right now it would not preserve the aspect ratio of the image). I tried setting the `contentMode` of the button and the button's `imageView` (note I set the button to a `Custom` Type, not `System`) to `.ScaleAspectFill` but that did not do anything.

The closest I came was by ditching the background image entirely and using `setImage` instead. This code was able to fill the button horizontally, but it shows the middle of the image, not the top. It also had odd functionality where if the scaled image was the same height as the button, it was not showing the full image (about 5 px were cut from the bottom and top). Here is that code:

```
imagesButton.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
imagesButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Fill
imagesButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
```

I have looked at about 5 stack overflow posts regarding image resizing in UIButtons, but I can't find the right set of settings that solve my particular need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution is an option for you, but the best way to achieve what you're trying to do, and give you pretty as much flexibility as you'd like with positioning and scaling the image, it to use a UIImageView (maybe even with a UIView that wraps it, for more image processing options) with a transparent custom button on top of it.

The upside to this approach is that you'll be able to do pretty much anything you want with the image and the way you display it. The downside is that you lose some of the default UIButton features (such as automatically altering the image when touched). But you can achieve these features programmatically if you want.